# Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) : Need at least two classes to do classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm having a problem when using the k-fold cross-validation with the Random Forest method. One of the outputs is the error "Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) :   Need at least two classes to do classification." However, I already have two classes to do the classification, which are "Normal" and "Failure". Someone could help me?

The R script:

```
library(caret)    
library(randomForest)

data_failures <- read.csv('OUTPUT.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
model <- train(Period_1 ~., data = data_failures, method = "rf",
                                   trControl = train.control)
print(model)

print(class(str(data_failures)))
```

The ouput:

```
Random Forest

112 samples
 11 predictor
  2 classes: 'Failure', 'Normal'

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold)
Summary of sample sizes: 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, ...
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy  Kappa
   2    1         NaN
   6    1         NaN
  11    1         NaN

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
'data.frame':   112 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Period_1 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_2 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ Period_3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_4 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_5 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_6 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_7 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_8 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_9 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_10: Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_11: Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_12: Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
[1] "NULL"
Warning messages:
1: model fit failed for Fold08: mtry= 2 Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) :
  Need at least two classes to do classification.

2: model fit failed for Fold08: mtry= 6 Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) :
  Need at least two classes to do classification.

3: model fit failed for Fold08: mtry=11 Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) :
  Need at least two classes to do classification.

4: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

A sample of the data:

```
    Period_1 Period_2 Period_3 Period_4 Period_5 Period_6 Period_7 Period_8
1     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
2     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
3     Normal   Normal  Failure   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
4     Normal  Failure   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal  Failure
5     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
6     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
7     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
8     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
9     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
10    Normal  Failure   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
```

Comment: What does `table(data_failures$Period_1)` return? Are your events pretty rare? Is it possible a subset is chosen for training that doesn't have any variability in the response?

Comment: Return Failure 1 and Normal 111. Yes, the events are pretty rare in these periods. About the question on the training subset, I'm not sure how the algorithm chooses this subset given that I have 112 subperiods in each Period, which can be "Normal" or "Failure"..

Comment: Well, your model just seems to be predicting `Period_1` status based on all the others. When the data is being split into folds, most of those won't work because they will have only one type of event and you can't predict if the outcome is constant. This doesn't sound like the right model for your data. You should probably as over at [stats.se] for recommendations for statistical models given your data and your prediction/estimation/modeling needs.